# Multivariable continuity and partial derivatives question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

P1 : Given $f(x) = x$ if $y=0$,  $x - (y^3)\sin(1/y)$ when $y$ is not equal to $0$. Is $f$ continous and differentiable at at $(0,0)$?

P2. Given $f = x  \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} /  |xy|$  when $x$ is not equal to $0$

and $0$ when $x=0$. Then the value of partial $f$ w.r.t. $x$ and partial $f$ w.r.t. $y$ at $(0,0)$ are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, notice that $f_x(x,y)=1$ (for all $y$). This is continuous everywhere.

$f_y(x,y)$ is definitely continuous for $y \not=0$ (just differentiate your formula for $f$ when $y \not=0$):
$$f_y(x,y) = -3y^2\sin(1/y) -y^3\cos(1/y)(-1/y^2) = -3y^2\sin(1/y)+y\cos(1/y)$$

The case "$f_y$ when $y=0$" requires more care:
$$f_y(x,0) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x,0+h)-f(x,0)}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{x-h^3\sin(1/h) - x}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} h^2\sin(1/h) = 0.$$

Finally, notice that $\lim\limits_{y \to 0} f_y(x,y) = 0 = f_y(x,0)$.

In the end, we see that $f_x$ and $f_y$ exist and are continuous everywhere. Continuity of first partials of $f$ then implies differentiability of $f$ which implies continuity of $f$.

Your second function has issues. It isn't defined near $(0,0)$. Why? Notice that $f(x,y)=x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}/|xy|$ isn't defined when $x=0$ (which you've handled) but it's also undefined when $y=0$.

If you change the definition of (the second) $f(x,y)$ so that $f(x,y)=0$ for $x=0$ **or** $y=0$, then the first partials at $(0,0)$ are 0 (use the limit definition).

**Edit:** Details about the second computation...

$$f_x(0,0) = \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \dfrac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{0-0}{h} = 0$$

since $f(\mbox{anything},0)=0$ according to my "fixed" definition of $f(x,y)$.

Comment: for second question when using limit definition for partial for x i get lim as x goes to 0  |x| / x which dont seem to exist

Comment: Your second question's function's definition isn't defined on an open disk about the origin so you *can't* compute it's partial with respect to $x$ (or $y$). If you *fix* your definition, the answer will depend on how you "fix" it.

Comment: what will be computation if i fix second question way u have fixed in ans of urs

Comment: I added the computation to my answer. The computation of $f_y$ would be essentially the same.

Comment: Your answer seems fine but now my problem is if as a independenty question we take f as what it is defined for x not equal to 0 and then compute its partial derivative of x . how will that be  ?